# Barcode Reader C#

Tags: c#

I'm using a wireless bar code scanner in desktop application to read the bar code and upon scanning events are firing and its working fine. I have a requirement where in the device, multiple scanners can be configured and based on each scanner id certain operation has to be performed.

How to retrieve the Wireless scanner Id ( as every scanner has an Unique Id).

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
  private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO Dummy);
 [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
```

Comment: I think this can help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182882.aspx

Comment: There's not nearly enough information about the system you are using. `GetLastInputInfo` seems irrelevant. Is it a bluetooth scanner or does it use some other technology? Do you use keyboard or serial port emulation for communication?

Comment: No Its a wireless laser Barcode scanner.

Comment: @DotNETDOUBT "wireless" could mean anything, Bluetooth? Wifi? Zigbee? Super-magical-advanced-quantum-entanglement? It may be that the scanner has an API. Have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: Device is connected to USB PORT.